# Mircea Merca's conjecteture

Tags: sequences-and-series, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Mircea Merca conjectured that $$\left \lfloor{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{k}}\right \rfloor=\left \lfloor{\left(\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{6n}\right)\sqrt{n+1}}\right \rfloor$$
John Zacharias claimed that he had proved this conjecture in this [article](https://maa.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/07468342.2018.1502997#.W_Cus2RKi2x). Did he actually prove the conjecture? How can I find the related article?

Comment: The asymptotic behaviour of $H_n^{(1/2)}$ can be found by summation by parts or creative telescoping. This is more a challenging exercise in Calculus than a ground-breaking conjecture.

Comment: This is [OEIS sequence A300287](https://oeis.org/A300287) which has a link to Thomas P. Wihler, [arXiv:1803.00362](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.00362).